# Loading external web-site element's content and filling out a sprite

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, import, external

My problem is that I am trying to have star/number rating from 3 different web-sites to be loaded into my review box (showing all 3 ratings separately, not an average of any kind).

So, first I need to extract the information of the external web-site's elements (divs, spans etc.), and second need to fill out a sprite, based on the numbers extracted from those elements. How can I do it?
I apologize in advance, if my question is stupid, but I am not even sure how to phrase it right to search for!

So, the codes used on the external web-sites are:

**1)**

```
 <span class="rating">
 <span class="average">8</span><span class="out_of">/<span class="best">10</span></span>
 </span>
```

**2)**

```
 <span class="b-hotel-rating__value" itemprop="rating">
 <span itemprop="rating">8.6</span>
 <span class="b-hotel-rating__value-limit">
  out of <span itemprop="best">10</span>
  </span>
 </span>
```

**3)**

```
 <span class="rate sprite-rating_rr rating_rr">
 <img class="sprite-rating_rr_fill rating_rr_fill rr35" width="63" property="ratingValue" content="3.5" src="http://static.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="3.5 out of 5 звезд">
 </span>
```

Where the numbers rating is used in the form of: n/10, I need to use the information to feed the function that would fill in a sprite (i.e. yellow stars out of gray stars).

Please help!

Comment: can't scrape a remote site html using client side javascript. You need to use server side scraper to do it or third party service like YQL

Comment: Oooookay, that doesn't sound too good! (Although I understood only a little). In this case, how can I insert an exact copy of a element that contains wht I want? I mean in a picture-like format? Or, using an acutal image is the only choice?

Comment: not sure what you are asking or what part of above you didn't understand. read up on how scraping works